# php как узнать и вывести все файлы в папке

Tags: php

В заголовке весь вопрос. Есть известная директория `site.ru/img/papka1/` в ней есть файлы `blabla.jpg` и `blablajh.jpg` как вывести полный адрес на php?
Результат должен быть такой:

`site.ru/img/papka1/blabla.jpg
 site.ru/img/papka1/blablajh.jpg`

Comment: Заголовок вопроса введенный в гугл выдает прямо то что надо, лол.

Comment: только ни один вариант не работает, в том числе `scandir()`

Comment: Ну так покажите код, который не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание, что путь в url может отличаться от пути к файлу в файловой системе. Поэтому читать вы должны из директории, а выводить url'ы.

Кроме того, очень рекомендую вам полюбить официальную [документацию php](http://php.net/manual/ru/). Она переведена на русский и содержит не только описания функций, но отличные примеры, рекомендации по использованию.

Среди прочего, из документации вы можете узнать о существовании функции `glob`, которая позволит сделать то что вам нужно максимально просто:

```
<?php

$url = 'site.ru/img/papka1';
$dir = __DIR__ . '/img/papka1'; // убедитесь, что директория указана правильно

foreach (glob($dir . '/*.jpg') as $fileName) {
    echo $url . '/' . basename($fileName), "\n";
}
```

Уаля!

Answer (score 0):

У меня был такой же вопрос с моим проектом, который был очень очевиден но я его не заметил))) Вот мое решение... (У меня по другому, но может тебе поможет)

```
<?php
    //Проверка директории (поставь свою директорию!!! (Если у тебя локалка то лучше делать так, по другому будет ошибка))
    $files = scandir('W:\domains\super-fizuka.com\view\docs');
    //Сортировка по названию (А, Б, В...)
    sort($files);
    //Файловая кнопка (Если тебе нужны названия просто пиши 'echo $file')
    foreach($files as $file){
       echo'<a class= link href="view\docs\\'.$file.'" class="product">'.$file.'</a>';
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Использую такой код:

```
 $dir = './img/papka1/';
        if($handle = opendir($dir)){
            while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                if($file != "." && $file != ".."){
                echo $dir. '' .$file. '|';
            }
        }
```

но он выводит вот так: `site.ru/wp-admin/img/papka1/blabla.jpg`

а нужно так `site.ru/img/papka1/blabla.jpg` из за этого столько времени потратила.

Comment: @doox911  Что не так с ответом? И тем более вопросом?

Comment: можете просто сделать замену через `str_replace()`, пример `echo str_replace('wp-admin', '', $dir) . $file`